# The isomorphism theorem of measure theory for atomic measures.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

There is the famous isomorphism theorem for measure spaces:

All separable nonatomic normalized measure algebras are mutually isomorphic.

what about an atomic normalized measure algebras?

Is it possible to establish an isomorphism or a measure-preserving transformation from an atomic normalized measure algebra into the measure algebra of the unit interval?

These theorems would be helpful in understanding my qeustion.
[image]
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
**Suggestion**

Let $\ (\mathscr{A},\mu)\ $ be a normalised atomic measure algebra with atoms $\ a_1,a_2,\dots\ $ of weights $\ w_1\ed\mu\big(a_1\big),w_2\ed\mu\big(a_2\big),\dots $ respectively, $\ (\mathbf{T},\nu)\ $ the measure algebra of the unit interval, $\ w_0\ed0\ $, and for each $\ i\ $ $\ \alpha_i\in\mathbf{T}\ $ be the class of  Lebesgue measurable sets equivalent to the interval $\ \left[\sum_\limits{j=0}^{i-1}w_j,\sum_\limits{j=0}^iw_j\right]\ $.  Then $\ \nu\big(\alpha_i\big)=w_i=\mu\big(a_i\big)\ $, and it looks to me like the measure algebra generated by $\ \alpha_1, \alpha_2,\dots\ $ should be isomorphic to $\ \mathscr{A}\ $ (but I haven't done all the i-dotting and t-crossing necessary to prove it.)

**Reply to query from OP in comments below**

On rereading this comment, it looks like I initially misunderstood it.  It now appears to me to be asking how to construct the isomorphism referred to in my answer above.

Since $\ (\mathscr{A},\mu)\ $ is an atomic normalised measure algebra, any element $\ a\ $ of $\ \mathscr{A}\ $ can be expressed uniquely as a countable join
$$
a=\bigvee_{\big\{i\in\mathbb{N}\,\big|\,\mu\big(a\wedge a_i\big)>0\big\}}a_i
$$
of atoms of $\ (\mathscr{A},\mu)\ $.  The assignment
$$
a\mapsto \bigvee_{\big\{i\in\mathbb{N}\,\big|\,\mu\big(a\wedge a_i\big)>0\big\}}\alpha_i
$$
will then give an isomorphism of $\ (\mathscr{A},\mu)\ $ to the subalgebra of $\ (\mathbf{T},\nu)\ $ generated by $\ \alpha_1, \alpha_2,\dots\ $.

Comment: But this is a measure-preserving, right?

Comment: Yes. It's obviously measure preserving on the generators, and  an atomic measure is completely determined by its values on its atoms (I was being obtuse in my earlier comment).

Comment: You have defined the measure preserving mapping between the atoms of normalized measure algebra and the measure algebra of the unit interval. But how would define a measure-preserving mapping between this two measure algebras?

Comment: what do you mean by this sign $\bigvee$? and why is it possible to represent any element $a$ in this way? Besides, how do you conclude that it is an isomorpism?

Comment: If $\ S\ $ is any countable subset of a Boolean $\sigma$-algebra (which any measure algebra must be) then $\ \bigvee_\limits{x\in S}x\ $ (or simply $\ \bigvee S\ $) denotes the supremum of $\ S\ $, which must exist by the very definition of Boolean $\sigma$-algebra.  That any member of an atomic Boolean $\sigma$-algebra can be written as the supremum of the set of atoms which it dominates is Lemma 1 on [p.70](https://archive.org/details/lecturesonboolea0000paul/page/70) of Paul Halmos's *Lectures on Boolean Algebras*.

Comment: See this theorem https://ibb.co/hHcscSD. it says that a necessary and sufficient condition that a measure space of total measure one be set isomorphic to the unit interval is that it be separable and non-atomic.

Comment: Yes, an atomic measure algebra obviously can't be isomorphic to the measure algebra of the unit interval.  If normalized, however, it can be (and always is, in fact) isomorphic to a *sub*-algebra of that of the unit interval, which I assumed is what your question was asking about.

Comment: @Ionza Ieggiera Hello can you please help me there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815845/would-we-have-the-preimage-of-at-least-one-interval-taken-out-from-01-insi ? I would be very grateful to you.