# Would We have the preimage of at least one interval taken out from $[0;1]$, inside the any ball taken out from $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is the theorem: [image]

Let $X$ be separable metric space endowed with non-atomic Borel measure such that $\mu X = 1$.

Using this theorem We can establish isomorphism between $X$ and $[0;1]$.

Denote this mapping by $f$ .

I want to show that for at least one positive-measured interval  $I \subset [0;1], \: \:$$f^{-1}(I\setminus I’) \subset B$, where $I’$ is the subset of $I$, of which measure is equal to $0$, i.e. $m(I’) = 0$,

where $B$ is any ball in $X$ with positive measure.

To sum it up I have to show that Inside every positive-measured $B \subset X$, We  would have the preimage of at least one subset of positive-measured interval taken out from $[0;1]$, of which Lebesgue measure would be equal to the measure of taken interval.

Is it possible to construct such isomorphic mapping or at least a measure-preserving mapping which would satisfy these conditions?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by a ball in a measure algebra?

Comment: @geetha290krm I have edited the question. $X$ is metric space.

Comment: You can always take $\ I\ $ to be the empty interval $\ \emptyset\ $, or if $\ b\ $ is any point in $\ B\ $ and $\  a=f(b)\ $, then you can also take $\ I\ $ to be the closed interval $\ [a,a]\ $ containing the single point $\ a\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I am afraid that you did n’t understand my question. I want to show that $f^{-1}(I) \subset B$ for at least one interval of form $[a;b]$, for every $B \subset X$. And remember that $X$ is separable non-atomic metric space so you would know how to define $B$. I would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: @JohnNash The interval $\ [a,a]\ $ is of the form  $\ [a,b]\ $. If the interval $\ I\ $ is required to have positive measure—i.e. $\ b>a\ $—then you should specify that explicitly in your question. But then it's not possible to satisfy the condition  $\ f^{−1}(I)\subset B\ $  with such an interval if  $\ \mu(B)=0\ ,$ and the conditions you've given aren't sufficient to guarantee that every ball will have positive measure. If you only require the condition to hold for balls $\ B\ $  with positive measure, then you should also specify that explicitly in your question.

Comment: Nevertheless, I've just realised that I was being sloppy in my first comment.  The isomorphism whose existence is guaranteed by the isomorphism theorem isn't a function from the metric space $\ X\ $ into the unit interval, but from the measure ring (using [Halmos's terminology](https://archive.org/details/measuretheory00halm/page/165/mode/1up)) associated with the measure space on $\ X\ $ onto the measure ring associated with the measure space of the unit interval.

Comment: While this will give rise to an associated function $\ \tilde{f}\ $from $\ X\ $ into the unit interval, that function is only uniquely determined as an element of $\ L^1(X,\mu)\ $, so it doesn't really make sense to talk of its values $\ \tilde{f}(b)\ $ at a single point $\ b\ $ of the unit interval. Since the two values $\ \emptyset\ $ and $\ [a,a]\ $ I suggested for $\ I\ $ in my first comment both have measure zero, however, they are both equivalent to the same element, zero, of the measure ring associated with the unit interval.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I have edited the question.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I have set quite high bounty on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=[0,1]$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure. Define the bijection $f$ of $X$ such that for each $x\in X$ we have $f(x)=x$, if $x$ is irrational, and $f(x)=1-x$, if $x$ is rational. It is easy to check that the map $f$ preserves measure. Let $B$ be the ball of radius $1/2$ centered at $0$. Then $B=[0,1/2]$, $B$ has positive measure, but there is no interval $I\subset [0,1]$ of positive measure such that $f^{-1}(I)\subset B$.

Comment: Does there exist a mapping for which my condition will be satisfied?

Comment: I was not able to construct such mapping Since X is not Specified.

Comment: @JohnNash I shall think about your new question.

Comment: Okay. If u provide me with the answer I will immediately give you this bounty and I will be very grateful.

Comment: There's a problem with this, in that, as I pointed out in one of my comments above, the isomorphism of the isomorphism theorem is a bijection between the measure rings associated with the two spaces, and not a function from $\ X\ $ to the unit interval. Although such a bijection can be specified by giving a bijection $\ f:X\rightarrow [0,1]\ $, all functions $\ g:X\rightarrow [0,1]\ $ that differ from $\ f\ $ only on a set of $\ \mu$-measure zero will give rise to the same bijection between the two measure rings.

Comment: The measure ring isomorphism $\ \beta_f\ $ corresponding to your function $\ f\ $ is just the identity: for any $\ A\ $ in the measure ring associated with $\ (X,\ell)\ $, $\ \beta_f(A)=A\ $. Thus $\ \beta_f^{-1}\left(\widehat{\left[\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8}\right]}\right)=\widehat{\left[\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8}\right]}\subset$$\,\widehat{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]}\ $, where $\ \widehat{S}\ $ denotes the member of the measure ring associated with the Lebesgue measurable set $\ S\ $.

Comment: Note that $\ \widehat{S_1}=\widehat{S_2}\ $ if and only if $\ \mu\big(\big(S_1\setminus S_2\big)\cup\big(S_2\setminus S_1\big)\big)=0\ .$

Comment: @JohnNash For the measure space $\ X\ $ and ball $\ B\ $ defined by Alex Ravsky in his answer, the interval $\ I=\left[\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8}\right]\ $ and identity function $\ g(x)=x\ $ for all $\ x\in[0,1]\ $ will satisfy your condition $\ g^{-1}(I)\subset B\ $ *for that example*. However, even appropriately interpreted as indicated in my comments, the statement in your question seems quite difficult to prove, and I'm not convinced that it's true.

Comment: But $X$ is not $[0;1]$ necessarily. $[0;1]$ satisfies the conditions of $X$, but it is just one particular example.

Comment: Quite.  As I emphasised in my previous comment the $\ g\ $ and $\ I\ $ I gave there only satisfy your required condition for the particular  $\ X\ $ and $\ B\ $ given in Alex Ravsky's answer.  As it is, though, his answer does give a nice counterexample to the conjecture *as you've stated it in your question.*

Comment: But, as I've tried to indicate in my comments,  your formulation of the question is based on a *misstatememt* of the isomorphism theorem itself, and it's possible to interpret it as a rather loose formulation of a genuinely interesting question about the isomorphism theorem which Alex Ravsky's answer doesn't address.

Comment: Is it possible to construct measure-preserving mapping which satisfies this condition? If we exclude the condition of isomorphism.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Your mapping gives us the difference on the set of measure zero. ( the measure of the set of rational numbers is 0) I need this mapping for integration so your mapping is appealing for me.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I have edited the question.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Please check it now.